# How to get oauth2 code param to redirect after login in the oauth2 auth code flow

Tags: spring-authorization-server

My app has custom login endpoint and the spring-auth-server redirects user agent to `/login`

Redirect to `login` After the following call

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8082/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oauth-dev&client_secret=secret&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&state=state123'
```

The current issue is my login endpoint can redirect to the redirect_uri: https://example.com, but I don't find how to get the oauth2 code param so it becomes

`"redirect:" + savedRequest.getParameterValues("redirect_uri") + "&code=" + code + "&state" = state;`

login endpoint

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(final HttpServletRequest request, String username) {
// the auth service mainly authenticates user by username/password
        authService.authenticate(username);

        SavedRequest savedRequest: =  request.session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST") as SavedRequest;
        return "redirect:" + savedRequest.getParameterValues("redirect_uri");
// it's missing code param. how to find the oauth2 code param?
    }
```

SecurityConfig

```
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http)
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer::class.java)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults())

        http
            .exceptionHandling { exceptions ->
                exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint ("/login"))
            }
            .oauth2ResourceServer {
                it.jwt()
            }
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authorizationServerSettings(): AuthorizationServerSettings {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authorizationService(): OAuth2AuthorizationService {
        return InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService()
    }

    @Bean
    fun registeredClientRepository(): RegisteredClientRepository {
        val registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("oauth-dev")
            .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUri("https://example.com")
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                .requireProofKey(false).build())
            .build()

        return InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient)
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwkSource(): JWKSource<SecurityContext> {
        val rsaKey = Jwks.generateRsa()
        val jwkSet = JWKSet(rsaKey)
        return JWKSource { jwkSelector: JWKSelector, securityContext: SecurityContext? -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet) }
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(jwkSource: JWKSource<SecurityContext>): JwtDecoder {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource)
    }
```

Specifically, I faced the issue at step 9 as shown in the following diagram. How can the login service at step 9 find the oauth2 code param?

[image]

I saw the code generation part is not reached

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java#L194

because of this condition

```
if (!isPrincipalAuthenticated(principal)) {
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java#L149

and the principal is `AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]`

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking based on the information provided so far. Can you explain your desired flow that the `/login` endpoint is attempting to facilitate? Have you reviewed the [official samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples)?

Comment: I already read the official samples. my app already has a custom /login endpoint and cannot rely on using formLogin() in the security config like the samples. how can it work w/o using formLogin()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Below is what I learnd:

Manually invoking the security filter chain within a controller is not recommended because it can bypass the normal Spring Security flow, potentially leading to security vulnerabilities.

In general, it is also not recommended to invoke AuthenticationManager manually within a controller. The AuthenticationManager is typically invoked by the security filter chain during the authentication process, and manually invoking it may result in unexpected behavior or security vulnerabilities

Thus, the custom endpoint for login is re-written using `.formLogin()` and a custom `successHandler` and a custom `failureHandler`

```
@Component
class LoginSuccessHandler() : SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

    private var requestCache: RequestCache = HttpSessionRequestCache()

    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authentication: Authentication
    ) {
        val savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response)

        // login is not from auth code flow
        if (savedRequest == null) {
          // custom logic
          return
        }

        // auth code flow
        val targetUrl = savedRequest.redirectUrl
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl)
    }

    override fun setRequestCache(requestCache: RequestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache
    }
}
```

```
@Component
class LoginFailureHandler(
) : SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {

    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        ex: AuthenticationException
    ) {
       // custom logic

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, ex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks "How to get state and code for redirect after login in auth code flow" but does not mention how the user is actually authenticated, or whether the Authorization Endpoint has been successfully invoked. Your login endpoint does not appear to authenticate the user, so I'm unclear on how it's supposed to work.

> I can see OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken has a attribute authorizationCode, but it's null

Based on your described issue, it sounds like you have not actually invoked the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint and generated an `authorization_code` yet, and so that's the next step.

The saved request you are retrieving after authenticating the user is actually the request to the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint. You will not yet have the `code` and `state` parameters, as those are created/managed by the Authorization Endpoint. So you have only to redirect to the `savedRequest.getRedirectUrl()` from the `SavedRequest` and you should be good to go.

You can (and probably should) use `HttpSessionRequestCache` instead of directly accessing the session, like this:

```java
private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

// ...

SavedRequest savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
String redirectUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
```

**Note:** It's not clear from your question what about the `redirectUrl` is not working, but it seems that you're expecting the wrong thing here.

---

If that doesn't quite clear it up, please add more details of what you're login endpoint is doing and what isn't working when you redirect to the `redirectUrl` from the `SavedRequest`.

Comment: Tks for providing the code snippet. I updated the question. The /oauth2/authorize endpoint is invoked and I still don't know where to retrieve the oauth code param. In this case should I still use HttpSessionRequestCache? Please feel free to request for further information.

Comment: I think the similar usage I could imagine: `.authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint.loginPage(CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_URI))`similar to the consentPage implementation `.authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint -> authorizationEndpoint.consentPage(CUSTOM_CONSENT_PAGE_URI))` or how the customize login page can work with spring-auth-server. hope it could help clarify my question

Comment: From updated question: "The current issue is my login endpoint can redirect to the redirect_uri: https://example.com, but I don't find how to get the oauth2 code param so it becomes". As I explained in my answer you seem to be expecting the wrong thing. You should not be performing the redirect to the client in your login controller. You have not actually invoked the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint _after_ authentication. Your diagram indicates an external service is being used for authentication. But Spring Authorization Server requires you to be authenticated _with_ the authz server itself.

Comment: It appears you are not authenticated with the authz server at all. Please see the [Federated Identity Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver) for an example of how to authenticate a user with SAS using an external (upstream) service such as another OIDC provider like Google and GitHub.

Comment: right, I can see `.oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> {
    oauth2Login.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);` can help the oauth2 login. I'm still confused how to add a handler for the login service? I imagine it's related to `if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` then delegate to the filterChain? but couldn't find the proper method to do so like the oauth2.login().successHandler().

Comment: @Holm, if you would like more assistance please post a full reproducible sample of your issue, as it will help everyone understand what your app(s) and configuration look like. The diagram you updated in your question seems to indicate multiple services, but it could be me interpreting your diagram incorrectly. Actual code will clear it up. If there are multiple (micro)services involved, please share all of the details. As I mentioned before, our samples do demonstrate many of the things you're trying to get working. If it doesn't help, please update the question with more details.